# Accessing googleapis fails

Tags: php, android, json, google-api

My user logs into my app, app sends idtoken to my server, server sends request to google, google sends userdata to my server, server puts it in my db. worked fine for 5 Months.
Now:

If I type in my webbrowser

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token= (+ idtoken of my google account extracted from my app)

I'll get the json with my name and so on in milliseconds as it should be.

today, since 6 hours, if my phpfile runs the command

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=".$idtoken;

$str =file_get_contents($url);
```

The page is loading and loading and finally returns no value.

I tried this version to get the .json file

```
$ch = curl_init($url); // such as http://example.com/example.xml
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$str= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

no fix with that.

I cannot install composer because no root access.

I contacted customer support, they told me everything is fine on the serverside.

Comment: Can you curl/ping the url from the console of your server?

Comment: curl also wont work! also very long loading time! `Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: Connection timed out
`

Comment: If curl/ping isn't working to that address on the server's command line then it is probably a routing/firewall issue. I would try a traceroute or ask your hosting provider to investigate

Comment: Support tells me `Please contact Google and check with them.` ? I asked them about firewall/routing and they say everything's ok

Comment: And: If I Try to do it without ssl, I DO get a json from google saying it needs ssl. only not working with ssl

Comment: Sounds like that port is being blocked. Can you hit anything else over ssl using curl?

Comment: It was arvixe.com  fault. port was blocked as you suggested!. They fixed it after 26 h. don't really reccomend this provider. Thanks for your suggestions. Do I have to delete this question?

Comment: I don't think you should delete it in case someone else has a similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after checking on the server's console that you can't curl to it over SSL, but can otherwise, it would suggest the port is blocked. Ask the hosting provider to open it.